# mmap vs malloc vs calloc performance microbenchmark: What to expect

Tags: memory-management, malloc, mmap, copy-on-write

I have created a microbenchmark to compare allocation performance and RSS usage for malloc vs mmap.

I'm coming to the conclusion that mmap is the fastest unless you actually use the memory. Therefore I could probably use it for sparsely populated data structures.

My questions are whether this conclusion is correct and the numbers I came up with make any sense (see below for details).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
int main()
{
#define SIZE 100
  void* allocated[SIZE];
  size_t size[SIZE];
  timeval then, now;
  memset(allocated, 0, sizeof allocated );
  gettimeofday(&then, NULL);
  size_t count = 0;
  size_t i = 0;
  for ( ;; )
  {
    if ( allocated[ i ] )
    {
      munmap( allocated[ i ], size[ i ] );
      //free( allocated[ i ] );
    }
    size[ i ] = rand() % 40000000 + 4096;
    allocated[ i ] =
      mmap( NULL, size[ i ],
          PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
          MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS
          /* | MAP_POPULATE */
        , -1, 0 );
    //allocated[ i ] = malloc( size[ i ] );
    //allocated[ i ] = calloc( 1, size[ i ] );
    //allocated[ i ] = calloc( size[ i ], 1 );
    i = (i+1) % SIZE;
    if ( !( ++count & 0xfff ) )
    {
      gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
      double timedelta = now.tv_sec-then.tv_sec + 1.e-6*( now.tv_usec-then.tv_usec );
      printf( "%f allocations/s\n", count/timedelta );
    }
  }
}
```

On my system (sandy bridge desktop machine), I get:

1. mmap: ~900.000 allocations/s, RSS ~0.5 MB, VSIZE ~2GB
2. mmap + MAP_POPULATE: ~800 allocations/s, RSS and VSIZE ~2GB
3. malloc: ~280.000 allocations/s, RSS and VSIZE ~2GB
4. calloc: ~550 allocations/s, RSS and VSIZE ~2GB
5. malloc, MALLOC_PERTURB_ == 1: ~260 allocations/s, RSS and VSIZE ~2GB

I have 'perf record'ed this a bit.

mmap + MAP_POPULATE spends most of the time in clear_page_c_e (2M calls/s), called from __mm_populate. I guessed that this would be the page fault tax that I would have to pay if the code actually does something with the mmap'ed memory, but...

...malloc (without the MALLOC_PERTURB_ environment variable set to anything) spends most of its time in clear_page_c_e as well (also 2M calls/s), but achieves many more allocations/s.

calloc and malloc with MALLOC_PERTURB_ spend all of their time in memset. I understand that for malloc. I thought that calloc is supposed to map all pages to a copy-on-write page of all zeros, but my glibc does not do that, apparently.

Everyone except plain mmap increased RSS, which was a little surprising to me. I thought that malloc and/or calloc would only do this when using the memory.

Comment: Allocating randomly-sized buffers isn't realistic. Programs have characteristic access patterns, and if you want to know how your program will perform, you need to simulate its access pattern. If you just want to know how fast `malloc` and `mmap` are, then run this benchmark for various fixed allocation sizes.

Comment: @larsmans Good point. Changing mmap to use a fixed allocation size does not change anything on my system, but malloc behaves very differently.malloc'ing 40MB buffers is still in the order of 280.000 allocs/s but without a growing RSS. malloc'ing 4096 byte buffers achieves ~33.000.000 allocs/s and still 4.000.000 allocs/s with MALLOC_PERTURB_. Both of this beats mmap/mmap+MAP_POPULATE.

Comment: Interesting. On Linux systems at least, `malloc`'ing multiple dozen megabytes actually results in a call to `mmap`, while smaller allocations use a custom allocator.